# Rails app slowed down after introducing database_cleaner gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working on a rails 3 app. Recently I have introduced database_cleaner gem. Since then, the app is extremely slow. Starting the server takes around 20 seconds. Is there something I need to do to the database_cleaner to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened with me some time ago. Check if you have a hidden folder *.bundle*. If yes delete it. It worked for me.